# use different "From" header for different actions when sending emails

Tags: 7, emails

So for example, when a user's creating an account, I want to have the sent email use "From: register@example.com" header.

But also, when I will approve his content I want to use the header "From: info@example.com"

Right now, all emails sent are using the same "From" email header provided in the "Site information" settings.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use [hook_mail_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) function in your custom module and change the from address based on your requirements.